# How to integrate Facebook to an iPhone application using Graph API

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing an iPhone app which needs Facebook to be integrated to my application. I tried using Graph API for that but it wasn't successfull.

I successfully logged into FB using the graph API and got the access_token to access FB.

The primary need for me is to get a Facebook page and get ALL the posts from that Facebook page. And also to post on the wall of that Page.

Plaese help me with that.

Thanking you in advance :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to share or post by mail from the current application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10860652/how-to-share-or-post-by-mail-from-the-current-application)

Comment: @TheTiger this question asked before question pointed in your comment

Comment: Yeah True. Don't know why this was being shown in `New Questions` in iPhone tag, I didn't notice the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using FBConnect library? https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk

I think it will solve all your problems

Comment: I am using the Facebook Graph API. I got the responce from Fabebook as a JSON Object array. Does this SDK provides an easy way to obtain parsed data from the JSON array ?

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't. You have to look through the dictionaries and parse them yourself. But that's not hard at all, just create a data model classes like "Post" with properties "User", "Message", "Time" etc. And loop through the whole response Dictionary creating Post objects and adding them to some temporary array. That's quite easy, think this through.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the facebook [permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/). Your user must allow you to access this information (you can do this with the [FB SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/iossdk/)). You can get info on the exact error from the server response. It looks like you want the `read_stream` and `publish_stream` permissions.