# How to share or post by mail, twitter and facebook from the current application?

Tags: iphone

I am implementing an application from which I have to share that applications on Facebook, [Twitter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twitter) as well as by mail. As my application is not a game, I just want to put an application icon, application name, iTunes link of that application and a small description of the application. I have implemented code which allow me to send a mail with attachment. Is that useful here? How can I do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**1. For Facebook.**

**FBGraph** is a much better way to use the **Facebook API** in your application.

Download the **FBGraph API** documents folder and then add it to in your folder. Read the instructions on the [Facebook developer site](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/).

This is [the sample code](http://github.com/reallylongaddress/iPhone-Facebook-Graph-API) and let me know if you have any query about it.

**2. For EMail**

Add `MessageUI.framework` in your project. Import the header file in your `ViewController.h` file:

```
 #import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h>
```

Set the delegate:

```
UIViewController<MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>
```

And after that, open your mail composer like this:

```
-(void)yourEmailbuttonClick:(id)sender
{
    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [picker setSubject:@"Hello!! your subject here"];

    // Set up recipients
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"anyImage.png"];
    NSData *myData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
    [picker addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"image/jpg" fileName:@"image"];
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}


- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{
    // Notifies users about errors associated with the interface
    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            //        message.text = @"Result: canceled";
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            //        message.text = @"Result: saved";
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            //            message.text = @"Result: sent";
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            //            message.text = @"Result: failed";
            break;
        default:
            //            message.text = @"Result: not sent";
            break;
    }
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

**3. For Twitter**

Add `Twitter.framework` in your project. Import the header file in your `ViewController.h` file and import:

```
#import <Twitter/Twitter.h>
```

Now call the Twitter composer view like this:

```
-(void)yourTwitterbuttonClick:(id)sender
{
    if([TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet])
    {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"anyImage.png"];
        TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetViewController = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
        // Set initial text
        [tweetViewController setInitialText:@"your text here"];

        if (image)
        {
            [tweetViewController addImage: image];
        }

        tweetViewController.completionHandler = ^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result)
        {
            if(result == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultDone)
            {
                // The user finished composing a tweet
                alert.title=@"Status";
                alert.message=@"Tweet sent";
                [alert show];
            }
            else
                if(result == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultCancelled)
                {
                    // The user cancelled composing a tweet
                    alert.title = @"Status";
                    alert.message = @"Tweet cancelled";
                    [alert show];
                }
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        };
        [self presentViewController:tweetViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you... You told about facebook twitter and mail, but can you plz tell me same for linkedIn?

Comment: Sorry @user1411780 -  i didn't use linkedIn API yet but if i get it i will definitely share the knowledge... :)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [ShareKit](http://getsharekit.com/).

This is a list of supported services:

> Supported Services:
>
> Delicious
> Email
> Facebook
> Google Reader
> Instapaper
> Pinboard
> Read It Later
> Tumblr
> Twitter

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this one by one.

Facebook    http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/iossdk/

Twitter https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Twitter/Reference/TWTweetSheetViewControllerClassRef/Reference/Reference.html

Mail http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html