# iOS app misconfigured for Facebook integration

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I am using the facebook-iphone-sdk framework to integrate my iPhone app to FB. The problem is when I click the button it gives an error "The application you are using is misconfigured for the Facebook integration. Please download the latest version of the app."

I was able to connect with FB only once. For the first time it worked fine and I was also able to post some data into my wall but afterwords it not working, and the above error occurs.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: You should me more specific and show us some code what you have and error pictures etc

Comment: I seriously doubt that the Facebook SDK was returning an error with "u r" in the error string, so I edited this into shape. In the future, we'd appreciate it if you didn't use textspeak abbreviations in your questions. Full English words make things a little easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you are using the deprecated API of facebook... Please use the New FBGraph API for facebook integration ....

[How to share or post by mail, twitter and facebook from the current application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10860652/how-to-share-or-post-by-mail-from-current-app/10862865#10862865)

This is not only about email... here you will find the tutorial and sample code for facebook integration.....!!

Answer (score 1):

The Bundle ID is case sensitive so watch out for that.

e.g. com.myapp.MyApp is not the same as com.myapp.myapp

This happened to me and gave the same error message.

Comment: This was my problem, the weird thing was that it worked for a few weeks before it didn't yesterday, because of this...

Answer (score 0):

Possible Solutions:

1) Double Check that you are putting in the right facebook app id in your code, and that you didnt somehow overwrite that when you made it work the first time.

2) Check that in the facebook developer profile you have all the proper things set up (They have decent doc's for how to set up properly).

3) Check that you are using the most up to date version of the SDK for fb.

4) Consider using the built-in Facebook for iOS6, since you probably wont be releasing your app before iOS 6 comes out anyways.

5) If all else fails, start over and go through the instructions from beginning to end. Check and re-check everything you set up and carefully scan for little typos or something. It's probably a minor mistake somewhere that you're overlooking.

6) Post code if you want more specific help. An error message isnt enough to deduce what your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete you app from facebook dashboard, create it again, and then change the facebookID in you App-Info.plist, in the key FacebookAppId and URL types array key. I did it and my app works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Delete facebook app, force perform login in safari..