# How to Post an Image to facebook wall?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, fb-graph

Using this Tutorail i scceessfully login to Facebook 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/1626/how-to-post-to-a-users-wall-upload-photos-and-add-a-like-button-from-your-iphone-app
But i have NO Experience with facebook for iOS .

```
- (IBAction)rateTapped:(id)sender {
     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"YOur Image url"];
     NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
     UIImage *img  = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
     [variables setObject:img forKey:@"picture"];
     FbGraphResponse *fb_graph_response = [fbGraph doGraphPost:@"/me/photos" 
    withPostVars:variables];    
  }
```

But here i confused that how we can pass image url ,bcz my image is on the same page And also when i use this code its gives me following four Errrors.

[image]

I have no luck. What's wrong? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see this post - [How to share or post by mail, twitter and facebook from the current application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10860652/how-to-share-or-post-by-mail-from-current-app/10862865#10862865)
In this you will found How to share an `UIImage` to **Facebook**, **Twitter**, and **Email**.

Comment: Thanx for reply ....your  Code Work for me but can u have idea that how we can post on frineds wall using this code.

Comment: Just replace the id with your friend id then try ..... and please accept the answer if it is working :-)

Answer (score 0):

**1st error is due to an **undeclared variable***.*
You are **not added Facebook sdk** to your project, that's why you are getting **2,3 & 4th errors**.
For using Facebook features in your application you need to integrate Facebook API to your project.
The latest face book API is known as Graph API.
For further reference visit http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

How to integrate Facebook sdk to your project:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/77/how-to-post-on-facebook-with-your-iphone-app