# Not able to handle the session properly

Tags: iphone, facebook, access-token

I'm using Xcode 4.3.1

I use the below code to get the Facebook access token.

In Appdelegate:

```
facebook=[[Facebook alloc]initWithAppId:appid andDelegate:first];
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] 
    && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) 
{
   facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
   facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
   accessToken=facebook.accessToken;
   date=facebook.expirationDate;
}
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [ self.facebook handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

Facebook SSO (login)
  In viewController:

-(IBAction)LoginClick:(id)sender
    {

```
    accesstoken=xapp.accessToken;
    date=xapp.date;
    [self fbDidExtendToken:xapp.accessToken expiresAt:xapp.date];  //For extending tokens
    NSLog(@"accesstoken:%@",accesstoken);
    if (![xapp.facebook isSessionValid]) 
    {
        [xapp.facebook authorize:permissions];
    }
    else 
    { 
        [xapp.facebook authorize: nil];

    }
}
```

Here I can't able to handle the sessions properly.My requirement is for the first time user must login and he should authorize the app.Once he done the app should not ask for authorization.Bt now its asking authorization for each and ever time I'm running the app.How can I solve this.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do u save the token to user defaults after login ?

```
 // this is a delegate method of FBSessionDelegate, called after user successfully login
- (void)fbDidLogin 
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[xapp.facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [defaults setObject:[xapp.facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

Comment: Are u sure the application:openURL:sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation: method get called? put a breakpoint to check if it does. And what happen when u run your code, do u get to the Facebook login screen?

Comment: s I can and even I can get the username,gender and other stuffs which don't need access token ..... PLz have a look at my latest edit in my question..

Comment: Are u sure u save the accessToken and expriationDate in fbDidLogin? try to check those values in fbDidLogin

Comment: Nw I can get the tokens... Bt not able to handle the sessions properly

Comment: Do u ever reach the line facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"]; ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Latest FBGraph API.... Check this link [How to share or post by mail, twitter and facebook from the current application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10860652/how-to-share-or-post-by-mail-from-current-app/10862865#10862865) for further queries. This post includes all the latest techniques for FB, Twitter and EMail.