# Facebook API SDK 3.0 "An error occurred with app"

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook-graph-api, ios5

I am doing ios integration with facebook and I just added Facebook login. i am able to login with my facebook account,

but my friend tested it, when he tries it, it gives him the error message that says "An error occured. Please try again later."

However, when I tried to login myself with my own Facebook account, I was able to register successfully. So I'm not sure what's wrong.

Can someone give any solution ?

Comment: [See this link for facebook integration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10860652/how-to-share-or-post-by-mail-from-current-app/10862865#10862865)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was facing the same error with my app,

i found that "Sandbox Mode" flag is set to true, it was causing this error,
it sets that only developer can use there account to signin,

set it to false, and you are all done!!!

may be it will help you :)

Comment: Hi, In my appId Sandbox is already disabled.Then also same error is coming.