# iOS sharing "An error has occurred. Please try again later."

Tags: ios, facebook, sharing

I am making publication via [FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModally...]
It works fine.
But if I delete application in the facebook settings and try make post again, I get login dialog within web publication view.
And after log in I get an error: "**An error has occurred. Please try again later.**". No callbacks called.

How can it be fixed?

[image: Log in form]
[image: Error after log in]

Comment: Why not just use the Facebook framework included with iOS 6? It saves you the whole hassle of authentication.

Comment: I must support both iOS5 and iOS6. Using web dialogs for both is simpler.

Comment: refer this link "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12366833/facebook-api-sdk-3-0-an-error-occurred-with-app"

Comment: Sandbox mode is disabled. Error happens after I delete app from my facebook account settings. All works fine until that.

Comment: Can you please file a bug report for this on: developers.facebook.com/bugs

Thanks!

Comment: Here is my bug report: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/130944707095100

Comment: Thanks. We're looking into it. Watch out for updates on the bug report.

Answer (score 7):

Seems like a bug in the SDK.

Try specifying your `app_id` in the parameters dictionary passed to `[FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:parameters:handler]`

The [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) says "Required, but automatically specified by most SDKs" however I found it was not happening automatically.

Comment: It works perfect when I added app_id into params.   NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"[YOUR ID]", @"app_id", @"Facebook SDK for iOS", @"name",
             @"Build great social apps and get more installs.", @"caption",
             @"The Facebook SDK for iOS makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated iOS apps.", @"description",
             @"https://developers.facebook.com/ios", @"link",
             @"https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png", @"picture",
             nil];

Comment: Hi, even i added app_id, I am getting this error. Any one have solution for this. Actually i am getting this error only when i post large content (above 4 lines) in "Message" Param

Comment: Seems strange but it works with me too when I add app_id into the parameter. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can get this error when your app is not available to the public (big slider on "Status & Review" page of the Facebook developer control panel says "NO"), and you have not added the account you log in with in the app as a test user.

I had this situation where I had not yet added my test user (I am using a difference account than my personal one for testing) as a test user to the app.

You can add your test users in the "Roles" page of the Facebook developer control panel.

Comment: This is the answer. Thank you Martijn, you made my day!

Answer (score 0):

You can either add your FacebookAppID to the passed parameters, as nick suggests. Or make sure your FacebookAppID is in your plist info file.

Add a string key: FacebookAppID with the value of your Facebook App ID. Then the SDK can automatically add your app id for use everywhere else.