# Do I need a Facebook app to let my iOS app post on someone's wall?

Tags: ios, facebook

I want to add a simple button in my iOS game that posts someone's score in their wall, perhaps with a link to the iTunes page of the app.

Do I need to create a Facebook Developer App for this? My problem with this is that apparently the SDK's sharing functionality won't work until the (Facebook) app is approved by the Facebook team, but in order to review the (Facebook) app, the team needs to be able to actually test it - but my game isn't finished and is not on the Appstore yet, so they can't review it...

Comment: at least for the sandbox mode of an facebook app, you don't need to have it reviewed - have you checked your settings?

Comment: @LordT: I was having the problem described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231939/redirecting-to-authentication-dialog-an-error-occurred-please-try-again-late) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16169133/ios-sharing-an-error-has-occurred-please-try-again-later), and apparently it is because I am in sandbox mode, which won't let me share to the wall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** Didn't realized the full question, you will need it to be verified before you start using it, however there's a sandbox mode that will let you work in the meanwhile. Go to your facebook developer profile and I believe in "Basics" section there¡s sandbox toggle.

[Facebook API and Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/)