# How to add a Facebook like page functionality in iPhone app?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-like

I have to add "Facebook Like page" functionality in an iPhone app could anybody help me how do it. I have searched for it but didn't find any API for iOS.

In my app I have to give a like page option to users. Users will like our page and then they will get full access of other contents of our application.

How can I know that user have liked our page or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First see my answer here - [How to share or post by mail, twitter and facebook from the current application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10860652/how-to-share-or-post-by-mail-from-current-app/10862865#10862865)

Here you can learn how to post comment, Image on `Facebook`.
There is a sample code also, Download and try it.

Now come to your point how to make a `like button`. So for this `Facebook` has provided a `POST` method through which you can send a request for like any object.

This is the method of like where **313449204401** is ID of object - 
https://graph.facebook.com/313449204401/likes

For sending request you will have also need an **access token**. How to get an **access token** you can know by sample code.

For more Read `FBGraph` API methods here - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/