# An iOS application with a Like button that likes Facebook page

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I am writing an iOS application that needs to set "likes" in Facebook page by button clicking.

When I send `me/og.likes POST` request with `params("object" - URL to Facebook page and "access_token")`, I get answer: `(#100) Like actions are not yet supported against objects of this type.` I used the method `requestWithGraphPath` from `FBRequest`.

I use latest `FacebookSDK.framework`. Does it contain an other needed functionality for setting "likes"? (I see property "likes" at `FBOpenGraphAction.h`)

Please help me with the correct way to set the likes.

Thank you!

Comment: Possible Duplicate Question 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12388793/how-to-add-a-facebook-like-page-functionality-in-iphone-app

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't, Facebook graph API doesn't allow to like pages using different apps than theirs. You can only like objects such as photos, urls etc. You can use urlscheme to load the FB application and make the user able to like the page from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a UIWebView and fill it with the HTML for Facebook's like button.
See [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1626/how-to-post-to-a-users-wall-upload-photos-and-add-a-like-button-from-your-iphone-app).