# Facebook SDK wont post on wall

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, facebook

After reading almost every question and answer, still can't get it to work.
Why do I keep getting this error when trying to post on my facebook wall?

```
2012-09-19 11:57:17.389 projectQuantity[5131:f803] received response
2012-09-19 11:57:17.390 projectQuantity[5131:f803] The operation couldn’t be completed. (facebookErrDomain error 10000.)
2012-09-19 11:57:17.391 projectQuantity[5131:f803] Err details: Error Domain=facebookErrDomain Code=10000 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (facebookErrDomain error 10000.)" UserInfo=0x6a9c100 {error=<CFBasicHash 0x6a9b140 [0x1743b48]>{type = mutable dict, count = 3,
entries =>
2 : <CFString 0x6a9b420 [0x1743b48]>{contents = "type"} = <CFString 0x6a9b5b0 [0x1743b48]>{contents = "OAuthException"}
3 : <CFString 0x6a9b550 [0x1743b48]>{contents = "message"} = <CFString 0x6a9b4b0 [0x1743b48]>{contents = "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."}
6 : <CFString 0x6a9be30 [0x1743b48]>{contents = "code"} = 2500
```

Why is that happening? thanks everyone.

Comment: What're you using **FBGraph** API or **shareKIT** .... I would likt to suggest for **FBGraph** ..... see this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10860652/how-to-share-or-post-by-mail-from-current-app/10862865#10862865

Comment: authentication process which has active access token which should be used to post on your wall...

Comment: so what I did so far, using Facebook SDK is wrong?

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to make the request?

Comment: ok, I've used this: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/ and now it's working perfect with dialog. Thanks alot everybody.

Comment: @YossiTsafar Can you please post the worked code for you,I do acknowledge you have provided us with the link,I am using Facebook 3.0 sdk,I want to post on friends wall on his/her birthday,please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an old question using the very old Facebook SDK, but now, with the new Facebook SDK it's easier than ever.

Already solved. Thanks everybody.

Download it here and follow the guide: http://developers.facebook.com/ios/

Enjoy.